# optimize sql query laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i'm trying to optimize this query i have for downloading sales report in laravel, with this query downloading a 1 month report consisting of 3000+ row took about 10 minutes which is unacceptable. what can i do to optimize this query so it can run faster?

```
$query = OrderDetail::where(['order.status' => 1])
    ->whereBetween('order.created_at', [$start, $end])
    ->select(
        'order_detail.id as no',
        'order_detail.order_id as id',
        'order_booking.booking_number as booking_id',
        'order_booking.sales_code as sales_code',
        DB::raw('CONCAT(customer.first_name, " ", customer.last_name) as fullname'),
        'customer.sap_code',
        'customer.phone_number as handphone',
        'order.created_at as date_order',
        'order.invoice_number as invoice',
        'order.so_number',
        'order.ro_sap as do_number',
        'order_shipping.*',
        'store_location.sap_code as kode_toko',
        'store_location.name as name_location',
        'order_detail.name as name_prod',
        'order_detail.model as model',
        'order_detail.product_price as a_pcs',
        'order_detail.qty',
        DB::raw('(IF(`order_detail`.`price` IS NOT NULL, (`order_detail`.`product_price` - `order_detail`.`price`), 0)) as discount'),
        DB::raw('(order_detail.qty*(IF (`order_detail`.`product_price` IS NOT NULL, `order_detail`.`product_price`,0))-(IF(`order_detail`.`price` IS NOT NULL, (`order_detail`.`product_price` - `order_detail`.`price`), 0))) as subtotal'),
        'metode.name as metode_pembayaran',
        'order_booking.tenor as name_tenor',
        DB::raw('(SELECT ov.voucher_code FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id <= 4 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1) as vch_code_product'),
        DB::raw('(IF((SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id <= 4 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),(SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id <= 4 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),0)) as payment_voucher_product'),
        DB::raw('(SELECT ov.voucher_code FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 5 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1) as vch_code_shipment'),
        DB::raw('(IF((SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 5 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),(SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 5 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),0)) as payment_voucher_shipment'),
        DB::raw('(SELECT ov.voucher_code FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 6 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1) as vch_code_bank'),
        DB::raw('(IF((SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 6 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),(SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 6 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),0)) as payment_voucher_bank'),
        DB::raw('(order_detail.qty*(IF (`order_detail`.`product_price` IS NOT NULL, `order_detail`.`product_price`,0))-(IF(`order_detail`.`price` IS NOT NULL, (`order_detail`.`product_price` - `order_detail`.`price`), 0)) - (IF((SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id <= 4 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),(SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id <= 4 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),0)) - (IF((SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 5 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),(SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 5 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),0)) - (IF((SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 6 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),(SELECT ov.discount FROM order_voucher ov WHERE ov.voucher_type_id = 6 AND ov.order_id=`order`.`id` ORDER BY ov.id ASC LIMIT 1),0))) as payment'),
        'order_status.name as name_status',
        'order_booking.channel as channel',
        'order_booking.device as device',
        'order_shipping.address as shipping_address',
        'order_detail.rating as rating',
        'order_detail.cwh_code',
        'order.shipping_cost',
    )
    ->join('order', 'order_detail.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
    ->join('order_booking', 'order_booking.id', '=', 'order.booking_id')
    ->join('order_shipping', 'order_shipping.order_id', '=', 'order.id')
    ->join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'order.customer_id')
    ->join('store_location', 'store_location.id', '=', 'order.store_location_id')
    ->join('order_status', 'order_status.id', '=', 'order.order_status_id')
    ->join('metode', 'metode.id', '=', 'order_booking.metode_id')
    ->orderBy('no', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'd also add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: have you try indexing your columns?

Comment: First of all, instead of having `->get();` use `->toSql();` so you get the query string. Then copy-paste it (replace `?` with the right values) in your terminal or whatever GUI you are using to run queries on your database. After that add `EXPLAIN` at the beginning of the query (before `SELECT`), so you can see what is it trying to do (using indexes? where? when? etc), then, I would try to write the same query with normal eloquent relationships and see if it still takes that long (just as a way of "debugging"), but have in mind that your query is a monster...

Comment: I know this isn't related to your question, but, try Jobs. You can place a button in your panel for generating sales reports. And then, you put a link in downloads section, so whenever your job is done, you just create a download record in database. Some queries need time. And yours, seems to be one of them. Also, for ````DB::raw('CONCAT(customer.first_name, " ", customer.last_name) as fullname')````, add a generated key (stored type) in your migration.

Comment: You have  a lot of queries from `order_voucher` in your select. They're going to be hard to optimize. See if you can get the data you want in a join, or just get the data you need beforehand in PHP in a single query and store them in memory

Comment: You are making a lot of subqueries inside your SELECT clause. This usually kills performance. This doesn't have much to do with laravel. It's something you need to rewrite from the grounds up. Try getting your data with another query inside your rdbms, try to avoid subqueries inside your SELECT clause. Prefer subqueries inside a JOIN clause or a FROM clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach.

1. You are loading all rows in memory.
2. You are joining many tables.
3. You are using too many subselects.

Use laravel eager loading to compose your rows for download. That will avoid the joins.

From FE call BE in chunks/pages. ExcelJS lib can stream the rows from the browser's memory to the computer disk as csv or xls. You can compose the row in js, BE will respond with the main model + relations as subobjects.
The browser must stay open until the download finishes. You avoid timeouts on the serverside.

PS. The data from subselects should be in the relations.